# Is it possible to take asp.net web adress from IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, iis-6

I want to read web services information especially adress from iis.
For IIS7 I can read following information with this code.

```
var iisManager = new ServerManager();
sites = iisManager.Sites;

foreach (var site in sites)

{
  IISService serv = new IISService();

  serv.Name = site.Name;
  serv.State= site.State.ToString();
  serv.PhysicalPath= site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath;

allServices.Add(serv);
```

}

For II6

```
DirectoryEntry IIsEntities = new DirectoryEntry(Path);

foreach (DirectoryEntry IIsEntity in IIsEntities.Children)
{
    if (IIsEntity.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
    {
        yield return new Website
        (
            IIsEntity.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(),
            GetPath(IIsEntity),
            (ServerState)IIsEntity.Properties["ServerState"].Value

        );
    }
}
```

I can read above information but I want to read end point information of asmx web service.
Thats like :
http://localhost:8091/Service1.asmx

Is it possible read port number or name of asmx file ?

Comment: No, it's impossible as they can be anythere outside the Path. You have to find the config file.

Comment: I can find Service1.asmx file when I ask for *.asmx  with  Directory.GetFiles in PhysicalPath. Actually port number is enough information for me .

Comment: Port is a administrative option, not corresponding to the files on disk.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. IIS has nothing to do with it. IIS only concerns about hosting-related operations and serving requests. If you are talking about services, you might want to look at making your services discoverable, exposing metadata and WSDL. However, this will not expose any file or any "internals" of the service...just the interface (public facing details)...for example if you have a RESTful service, the physical files behind it will not be exposed.

Comment: I can construct local adresses with binding information, look my  answer.

Comment: could you inspect my below answer?

Answer (score -1):

I ask IIS for local adresses so I can succeded to get enough information to form asmx local web adress.

```
foreach (var site in sites)
{
  IISService serv = new IISService();

  serv.Name = site.Name;
  serv.State= site.State.ToString();
  serv.PhysicalPath= site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath;

  System.Net.IPEndPoint endP = site.Bindings[0].EndPoint;

  string protocol =   site.Bindings[0].Protocol;

  allServices.Add(serv);
}
```

I can get Binding information with this solution(port and Protocol). I
 can find Service1.asmx file when I ask for *.asmx with Directory.GetFiles in PhysicalPath. So I get needed information to construct web services adress.

```
//What I need http://localhost:8091/Service1.asmx

string adress = protocol + "://localhost:" + endP.Port + "/" + " *.asmx file from PhysicalPath";
```

Comment: Getting binding info is related to IIS . I simple find the file so combine them, that solved my problem. So I wanted to inform you the possible solution.

Comment: This won't work if your code don't have such priviligies to read the files in a particular folder. Or service is being hosted in not-IIS default folder.

Comment: If I dont have such priviligies to run  Active Directory Domain Services codes this codes can not run entirely. Priviligies  is not the question as I said this solved my problem.